# Can Pi 3b+ be killed by wire under ethernet port

Tags: pi-3b+, troubleshooting

Can raspberry pi be killed by cable under ethernet port? I had moved pi on desk and placed it over a cable in area shown on picture (cable has only 5mm exposed wire), after that pi freezed and din´t boot again (red diode flash but not green one), i think a bus would be killed if shortcut ocured in this area?
sorry for poor english[image]

Comment: Hi there - welcome.

I'm not clear about the cable. Mains power? Telephone? LAN? Is that your Pi in the photo, it has no SD card fitted...

Comment: If by "cable" you mean a bare metal wire, of course that could cause a problem.  If you mean something sheathed in plastic or something else non-conductive, then it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes it could. Those pin leads sticking through the PC board are very sharp and will puncture through insulation. As long as the wires were connected to *anything* it could cause damage, including zero volts (ground). Without knowing exactly which pins touched, and tracing all paths (including ground paths) you'll never know for sure. 3.3v logic is a pretty wimpy.

For example, most modern AC adapter are isolated from earth ground, and in fact have voltage between the "-" side and earth ground (I've measured between 4 volts and 42 volts on various adapters. It's due the the voltage regulation circuit). It's usually a very low current, but enough to zap a Pi.

This topic could be debated forever because there are so many variables that can't be answered.